# How do subsequent steps follow? (Divergence and partial derivatives)

Tags: proof-explanation, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

Let $(x,y)$ evolve to $(X,Y)$ under the velocity field $\vec v=(u,v)$ in time $t$. Thus, $$X=X(x,y,t), Y=Y(x,y,t), t=t$$
Then, $$J(x,y,t)=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\partial X}{\partial x} & 
    \frac{\partial X}{\partial y} & 
    \frac{\partial X}{\partial t} \\[1ex] % <-- 1ex more space between rows of matrix
  \frac{\partial Y}{\partial x} & 
    \frac{\partial Y}{\partial y} & 
    \frac{\partial Y}{\partial t} \\[1ex]
  \frac{\partial t}{\partial x} & 
    \frac{\partial t}{\partial y} & 
    \frac{\partial t}{\partial t}
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\partial X}{\partial x} & 
    \frac{\partial X}{\partial y}\\[1ex]
  \frac{\partial Y}{\partial x} & 
    \frac{\partial Y}{\partial y} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now $\frac{\partial J}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial X}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

Thus,  $\frac{\partial J}{\partial t}$ is the trace of matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & 
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\[1ex]
  \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & 
    \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} 
\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\partial Y}{\partial y} & 
    -\frac{\partial X}{\partial y}\\[1ex]
  -\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x} & 
    \frac{\partial X}{\partial x} 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial X} & 
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial Y}\\[1ex]
  \frac{\partial v}{\partial X} & 
    \frac{\partial v}{\partial Y} 
\end{bmatrix}.J(x,y,t)$
Therefore, $\frac{\partial J}{\partial t}=(\nabla.\vec v)J$.

Now how did the steps after "trace of matrix" conclude? Also, why are we taking gradient with respect to $X,Y$ and not $x,y$ in the last step?